# What is the main difference between ScreenManager and Tabs is KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

To me both ScreenManager and Tabs seem like they do the same thing, what advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
The main difference is that both are used for managing multiple screens in the kivy application. 

1. ScreenManager
     clear and simple
     easy navigation and dynamic

     require more coding and setup
     difficult to manage

 1. Tabs
    Tabs provide an intuitive and familiar interface for users
    easy to set up

    difficult to navigate 
    when you have more screens it becomes cluttered
```